# xcode error :ld: framework not found GSS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I ported libsmbclient.a to iphone 5.0's simulator . it needs functions  "krb5_parse_name".
and  I add GSS.framework to project .

```
Ld /Users/hxy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SambaSample-dfgvsqckubfrxxdkscrdwvnewbxa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SambaSample.app/SambaSample normal i386
    cd /Users/hxy/Documents/ios_prj/SambaSample-sim
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/hxy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SambaSample-dfgvsqckubfrxxdkscrdwvnewbxa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/hxy/Documents/ios_prj/BNSmbRequest-sim/libsmbclient -L/Users/hxy/Documents/ios_prj/BNSmbRequest-sim -F/Users/hxy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SambaSample-dfgvsqckubfrxxdkscrdwvnewbxa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/hxy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SambaSample-dfgvsqckubfrxxdkscrdwvnewbxa/Build/Intermediates/SambaSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SambaSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/SambaSample.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lresolv -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -licucore -lz -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework GSS -lsmbclient -o /Users/hxy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SambaSample-dfgvsqckubfrxxdkscrdwvnewbxa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SambaSample.app/SambaSample

ld: framework not found GSS
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I added the framework following this steps: project -> targets -> linked frameworks and libraries -> +

what's wrong with me?

Comment: Have you added Framework search path in xcode build settings

Comment: Or maybe this framework hasn't i386 architecture for simulator, only for iphone (arm)?

Comment: I have found the reason： the GSS.framework isn't simulator version. -----------------                   find /Developer/ -name GSS.framework
/Developer//Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework
/Developer//SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework